# Creating a GMAIL filter that shows all of the "important" emails that are unread and not archived

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

So I'm trying to create a Gmail filter that shows me all of the important emails that are unread and not archived.

I'm using the following filter: `is:important AND is:unread and is:inbox` However it appears that it is only showing unread emails that are on the first page of the email and it is missing some of the emails that I have that are clearly marked "important" and they are unread.

In addition to that I have another filter that should just show me any email that is not important but unread, and I'm having a similar issue with that `is:unread and is:inbox -is:important`

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to use an `AND` between the filters.

Try this combination instead

```
is:important is:unread in:inbox
```